# Without using Row_Number() is there any other way to fetch row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I Use Row_Number () with SORT the, query plan is giving bad performance.like for SORT 34% Cost. Is there any other way to fix this. See last line in this query

```
        SELECT * FROM
          (
        SELECT   F.Id, 
                        F.FolderNo, 
                        F.FolderStatusDate, 
                        (SELECT codedesc 
                         FROM   cm.codetable 
                         WHERE  id = F.FolderStatusCode) 'FolderStatus', 
                        (SELECT codedesc 
                         FROM   cm.codetable 
                         WHERE  id = F.FolderLocationCode) 'Location', 
                        F.Volume, 
                        F.SDExhibits, 
                        F.Cost, 
                        F.Remarks,
                        Row_number() OVER(partition BY F.Id  ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ASC) RN                             
        FROM   cm.pfmfolder F WITH(nolock) 
               INNER JOIN cm.pfmfoldermstipmap PMMAP WITH(nolock) 
                       ON PMMAP.pfmfolderfk = F.id 
               INNER JOIN cm.mstip MST WITH(nolock) 
                       ON MST.id = PMMAP.mstipfk 
        WHERE  ( @FolderNbr IS NULL 
                  OR F.folderno LIKE + @FolderNbr + '%' ) 
               AND ( @ApplnNbr IS NULL 
                      OR MST.applnnbr LIKE + @ApplnNbr + '%' ) 
               AND ( @FolderStatusCode IS NULL 
                      OR F.folderstatuscode = @FolderStatusCode ) 
               AND ( @FolderLocationCode IS NULL 
                      OR F.folderlocationcode = @FolderLocationCode ) 
               AND ( F.folderstatusdate >= @FolderStatusDateFrom 
                     AND F.folderstatusdate < @FolderStatusDateTo ) 
               AND MST.registrycode = @RegistryCode 
               AND PMMAP.deletedby IS NULL 
                  ) AS T
            WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Since you're giving it an ambiguous sort order, the numbers are randomly assigned and so of no use anyway. Why do you want such numbers?

Comment: I need that numbers to filter out distinct data ...see updated query

Comment: Why not to use `TOP 1` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`?

Comment: Cannot use top one because in this scenario i will be getting 300K records with unique id's i:e not duplicate

Comment: So, the actual problem isn't to generate row numbers - it's to obtain one result for each distinct `F.Id` value. Well, the usual way to solve that without having to perform any sorting would be to look at your `JOIN` conditions and see if they can be tightened up. It would also usually be good to specify a rule (even if there's no strong preference at the moment) for which rows should be used to produce values in the other columns, specifically.

Comment: Have you tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By F.Id Order By F.Id)` ??

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that the `sort` clause has any real cost. You can compare two queries side by side with the actual execution plan turned on and see their contributions to the package, one query with and the other without the `row_number()` column.

It is actually the `partition by` clause that has some real operational cost.

Comment: Yes Cost on SORT is 36% for this query

Comment: @user1030181, compare subtree costs. Run two queries alongside with the actual execution plan turned on and tell us what their individual contributions to the package are.